# Copy numbered image files where number is less than X

Tags: linux, file, terminal

I have a folder of 10,000 JPEg's labeled `1.JPG` to `10000.JPG`. I want to copy all files that have a number less than (or greater than) X to another directory. What's the best way to do this from the command line?

Comment: Is `X` a variable, or do you know it beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple brace expression would zap this, here I am guessing at your number range of course:

```
cp {25..400}.jpg another_dir
```

More information on brace expressions here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion which includes:

> The syntax for brace expansion consists of either a sequence
>   specification or a comma separated list of items inside curly braces
>   "{}". A sequence consists of a starting and ending item separated by
>   two periods "..".